# What is string theory? Why was a new theory required when modern Physics was only one step away from establishing a G.U.T.?

Tags: forces, tensor-calculus, grand-unification

What is string theory ? (correct me if i am wrong) Why a new underlying theory was required when modern Physics was only one step away from establishing a G.U.T. (unification attempt for four fundamental forces out of which three could be clubbed.) using Tensor Flow ?

Comment: Some think String Theory *is* that one step.

Comment: TensorFlow as in [the software library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow)? It sounds like you may have been misinformed regarding our proximity to a GUT.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but yours truly can't actually call it Tensor calculus, me being so used to calling, processes of Differentiation and Integration as Calculus (as done by few other Lecturers in Indian universities also) Tensors seem to have more resemblance with Vectors and Algebra. Development of Tensors as a tool are attributed to Mr.A.Einstein who put an end to Newton's Mechanics as the "final verdict" in our understanding of Physical world. (heard that differnce equations were more prevalent in those times rather than much purer calculus that we are able to see today).

Comment: What do you mean by “clubbed”?

Comment: Are you aware that tensors (such as the moment of inertia tensor) are used even in Newtonian mechanics?

Comment: [Tensor calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_calculus) is named as such because it concerns the differentiation and integration of tensors.  Einstein used them, but they were developed by others.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia article about GUTs, you'll find that they try to unify only *three* forces. And so far they don’t seem to work.

Comment: Excuse me for my poor choice of words but as I've heard scientists in those times were able to "Generalize" three fundamental forces describing/formulizing it through a single equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory

Comment: The premise of your question is false. GUTs did not attempt to include gravity. They attempted to unify the strong force with the electroweak force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) describes string theory.

> In physics, string theory is a theoretical framework in which the point-like particles of particle physics are replaced by one-dimensional objects called strings. String theory describes how these strings propagate through space and interact with each other. On distance scales larger than the string scale, a string looks just like an ordinary particle, with its mass, charge, and other properties determined by the vibrational state of the string.

You ask:

> Why a new underlying theory was required when modern Physics was only one step away from establishing a G.U.T.

GUT , and normal field theoretical models have a problem with the mathematics, there are singularities when higher order terms are added that have to be taken out by hand. The effort for new theories is based on that, trying to find mathematically rigorous theories that would have no singularities.

[Supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) was proposed as one such possibility for the three forces, not including gravity.

String theory is explored by theorists because it has the possibility of including gravity in the model, and also embedding the standard model which is an encapsulation of practically all data up to now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ohneVal I have given my own opinion in my answer,the link is for further reference, but \\\\\ok, I will copy the  first sentence